# PHP upload settings, max file upload and chunks

Tags: php, upload

My host is on a shared server so therefore i cannot change the php.ini.  My goal is to upload files of upto 100mb but the servers `upload_max_filesize` is set to 6mb which i cannot change..

My quetsion is, is it possible to bypass this by uploading in chunks using something like https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is, since chunking breaks uploads in independent chunks that are uploaded as independent requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've now figured it..

By default `chunking` is not enabled.. you have to enable it in the jquery options, here is the source to do that https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads

For testing purposes i've changed my `php.ini` settings to accept only 1mb and i'm successfully loading files that surpass that max upload.

Comment: can you say how i you implement chunking in php ?